# After making my VM highly available I get "Could not find Ethernet switch" error when trying to live migrate

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, nic, windows-registry, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I normally create new VMs from the Failover Cluster Manager GUI.  But this time around I went a different route because I had to (due to time constraints and available resources at the time).  For this one VM I had to create it on cluster node1 directly.  Then when I got it up and running the cluster had the disk available for me to use so I shut down the VM, then added it as a service/role in the Failover Cluster Manager GUI.

That seemed to come over into the Failover Cluster Manager with no issues at all.

Then I tried to do a Live Migration and got the error "**Could not find Ethernet switch 'Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3 - Virtual Switch'.**"

A few things to note...

- The NICs are named the same exact thing on BOTH nodes.
- The NICs do seem to have the "device names" mixed up.

  - Node1 NIC's Name:NIC1
  - Node1 NIC's Device Name:'Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3 - Virtual Switch'.
  - Node2 NIC's Name:NIC1
  - Node2 NIC's Device Name:'Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2 - Virtual Switch'.
- I have all NICs enable and in use except for ONE, and that's NIC1.
- I could not find "Refresh the Configuration of a Virtual Machine" on Server 2012 R2 (like there was in Server 2008 R2).
- I tried refreshing the VM configuration by using '**Update-ClusterVirtualMachineConfiguration -Name "Virtual Machine Configuration A
  PAPTR"**' on both nodes (with no errors, just shows the VM status).
- I created a new VM via the Failover Cluster Manager GUI and it live migrates with no issues at all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out...

I kept thinking it was because of the WINDOWS "Device Name" in the Network Connections list.  I was completely wrong and it kept me going down the wrong path.

The real reason the issue was happening was due to the Virtual Ethernet Adaptor created by Hyper-V.  Each of your cluster nodes will have one (or should) in order to get your VMs a network connection.  To get to the Virtual Ethernet Adaptor you need to access the Virtual Switch Manager.  To get to that **open up the Hyper-V Manager**, on the left **right click the server node** (you can add all your nodes here to manage them rather than logging on to each one) and **select "Virtual Switch Manager..."**.  Once you do that, **click on the Virtual Switch** already created (below "New virtual network switch") or create a new one.  **The "Name" field needs to be the same on ALL nodes you plan on live migrating to.**  In my case I changed all mine to "HyperV Virtual Switch".

[image]